# 多対多のモデルで中間テーブルへの保存を必須とするバリデーションについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

例えば、UserとGroupの多対多のモデルに対して、中間テーブルUser_Groupがあるとします。

Groupを作成する際にuser_groupで最低一つのレコードを保持させる、つまり必ずUserと紐づかせた上で作成するようにバリデーションを組むにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

group.rbに
`validate: user_ids, presence: true`
を記述する方法が候補としてあるかなと思いますが、他にあるでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

中間テーブルの`user_group_id`を必須にするのはいかがでしょうか

```
validate: user_group_id, presence: true
```

という感じです。